# In Civ5, is it possible to buy a courthouse?

Tags: civilization-5

It seems I can buy most buildings, but the courthouse is not listed for purchase in my annexed cities.

Is it not possible to buy courthouses?

Comment: Related: [Speed Up Current City Production](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/speed-up-current-city-production)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Once the resistance is over, you can buy the Courthouse for 600 gold, which is slightly more expensive than other buildings that cost 100 hammers.

> Before the patch released on 15 December 2010 it was not possible to buy a courthouse

Comment: Cheers. It's just no fun building courthouses when happiness is at -45 and all production is reduced :-)

Comment: I definitely would not annex a city when happiness is at -45.

Comment: When happiness is that low you want to consider razing cities.  Chances are good that you have already annexed too many, so you may want to go through them and pick a few to raze.  It's remarkable how quickly your happiness comes back from dropping 4-5 of them.  You can always rebuild them later after you have built happiness buildings in the remaining cities.

Comment: the gold depends on the game length, e.g. on Marathon a courthouse costs 2 million gold approximately

Answer (score 10):

No, you cannot buy courthouses, but you *can* use a great engineer to speed building up to 1 turn (confirmed last night).

Comment: That's good to know.

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you have the spare money, you can buy Workshop, Windmill, etc to speed up production.

Answer (score 2):

As of the patch deployed on 12/15:

> - Reduced production cost and maintenance for the Courthouse.
> - Courthouse can now be purchased in a city (although it is expensive).