# How high is the production bonus of a great engineer in Civ5?

Tags: civilization-5

To quote the manual:

> Special Ability: Hurry Production
>
> You can expend a Great Engineer to create
> a sudden burst of production in a
> city. The production is immediately
> applied to whatever is presently being
> built in the city – unit, building or
> Wonder. This will usually be enough
> production to immediately finish all
> but the most massive Wonders, and it
> will drastically shorten their
> production time.

I had a great engineer during modern times, and using it to help produce the Statue of Liberty (1200 prod needed) **yielded 750 production**. Letting it help along for a Stock Exchange immediately finished this building (650 prod cost).

I assume that the amount of prod. generated is **somehow game-stage related**? Are there any known specific rules?

Comment: I'd say its also game speed related since all the build times are scaled

Comment: I was guessing this would be in one of the XML files, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The amount of production of a great engineer on **normal speed** is calculated using the formula

```
300 + 30 * city population
```

So in a city with a population of 1 the engineer only results in 330 production, in a size 15 it results in 750 production.

For **quick speed** the formula is:

```
200 + 20 * city population
```

For **epic speed** it is:

```
450 + 45 * city population
```

and for **marathon** it is:

```
900 + 90 * city population
```

The amount of hammers does not seem to be influenced by era, map size or difficulty level.

**Conclusion:**
If you want to hurry late game wonders, build it in a city with a large population.

Comment: Cool! Where did you get the numbers from?

Comment: I played around with Firetuner. Took me a bit to realize that population plays a role. I always got 330 hammers and wondered why this was different from the 750 in the question.