# How to calculate gold earned from a Wonder if another civilization finishes first?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

In Civilization V I noticed that when you are about to finish producing a Wonder and another civilization finishes it first, you will earn gold equivalent to how much production you have produced for that Wonder.

For example, I'm constructing the Statue of Liberty (total prod of 1060 prod points) and I've finished 1000 production then another civilization completes it first. How much gold will I earn?

Is there a formula for calculating money earned from unfinished wonders?

Comment: Can't say for sure but I believe it's equivalent to the amount of Gold you'd produce if you'd switched your city to producing wealth for those turns spent on the wonder.

Comment: I am not referring to 'other cities'. I am referring to 'other civs'.

Comment: I know. My response still applies.

Comment: Why don't you post it as answer with proof and explanation/s?

Comment: I currently don't have the proof required to make a decent answeras it's before work and time is limited. Don't want to answer without proof of accuracy.

Comment: I haven't independently verified, but [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/80017/30220) says 1 gold per hammer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I stop building a wonder if I find a rival is likely to beat me to it?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/78913/should-i-stop-building-a-wonder-if-i-find-a-rival-is-likely-to-beat-me-to-it)

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals, I think they are not the same. I am after the equivalent not the **choice on what to do while constructing a wonder**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tested this in a hot-seat game. Wonder fail-gold is 1 for 1. That is, you get 1 gold for every hammer input. This is a better return than the 1 gold for 4 hammers you get by building wealth.

Additionally, I checked the source code (Steam -> Tools -> Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK)
For Brave New World, in

```
...\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK\CvGameCoreSource\CvGameCoreDLL_Expansion2\CvCity.cpp
```

The relevant code block starts at line 12739 (function CvCity::doCheckProduction)

```
...
iProductionGold = ((iBuildingProduction * iMaxedBuildingGoldPercent) / 100);
...
thisPlayer.GetTreasury()->ChangeGold(iProductionGold);
```

**iMaxedBuildingGoldPercent** is 100, sourced from `GlobalDefines.xml`, for BNW found at

```
...\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\DLC\Expansion2\Gameplay\XML\GlobalDefines.xml
```